# Call asp method from c# code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

On a web application, I need to do some conditional logic and then based on that, possibly show a dialog box. Here's what I need to do:

1. Button pressed, submitting two IP Addresses
2. Check if these addresses are 'in use'

   1. If they are:

      1. display confirm box

         1. If "OK" is pressed, call C# function
         2. Otherwise, done
   2. If they're not:

      1. Call C# function

When the button is pressed, it calls the clicked method `btnLinkConnect_Click()` in the C# codebehind. This then checks for addresses 'in use'. Stepping through with the debugger, this all works fine, but if addresses are 'in use', a javascript script is supposed to run to display the box:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function askForOverride(station1, station2) {
        var answer = confirm("Station(s):" + PageMethods.GetActiveStations(station1, station2) + "is/are in use. Override?");
        if (answer) {
            PageMethods.uponOverride(station1, station2);
        }
    }
</script>
```

But how can I get this script to run from the C# page? I've looked at `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()`, but I couldn't get it to work, and it appears not to be able to work inside the conditionals. I've looked at ajax, but I couldn't understand exactly how to call it from the C# codebehind.

What is the best way to call this script, or obtain the same result, and how should I go about it?

Comment: Are you aware that JavaScript executes on the client-side, in the browser, and that the "code-behind" executes on the server-side?

Comment: Have a look at this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx

Comment: @DanielMann - yes I am

Comment: @SamHood - I did try that too, but I couldn't get it to work. Can it be done in a function other than PageLoad()? I've never seen it done anywhere else

Comment: As far as I know you can put it anywhere before the page is sent to the client.  What was the problems/errors you were facing?

Comment: @SamHood - I couldn't get the script to actually run. I'm not sure if the arguments were wrong, or what.

Comment: Double-check your script is working, Javascript just loves it's silent errors. Use F12 (in Chrome) to see if any exceptions are popping up when the script should be firing, and try running the script on it's own to iron out any problems.  RegisterStartupScript should execute the second the page gets back to the client

Comment: The console shows nothing when the script is supposed to run

Answer (score 1):

This may work, add some client events for button click based on condition. Please refactor if necessary

```
 protected void btnSumbit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {       
            //call some function to verify IP entered by user
            bool isExistingIp = VerifyIp(txtIP.Text); 
            if (isExistingIp)
            {
                // event argument PASSED when user confirm to override from client side
                string isoverride = Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"]; 
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(isoverride))
                {                
                    //register script if user hasn't confirmed yet
                    this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "displaywarning", "displaywarning();", true);
                    Page.GetPostBackEventReference(btnSumbit);
                }
                else
                {
                    //continue with functionality
                }

            }
            else
            {
                //continue with functionality
            }
        }
```

On client side add javascript to display warning and do a post back

```
 function displaywarning() {
            var isOverride = window.confirm("do you want to override");
            if (isOverride) {
                __doPostBack('<%=btnSumbit.ClientID%>', 'override');
            }
        }
```

Comment: It doesn't work. When I step through with the debugger, it does get to the `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` line, but nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with jQuery AJAX calls.

ASPX

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('body').on('click', '.performsMyClickAction', function () {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "BlogPost.aspx/TestIP",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.d = 1) //In use
        {
            $("<div>State your confirm message here.</div>").dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height: 210,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Ok": function () {
                        __doPostBack('<%= upnl.ClientID %>', 'InUse ');
                                        $(this).dialog("close");
                                    },
                                    "Cancel": function () {
                                        $(this).dialog("close");
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            __doPostBack('<%= upnl.ClientID %>', 'NotInUse ');
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
});
</script>          

<body>
<form id="form2" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" OnLoad="upnl_Load">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div>
                 <asp:Button CssClass="performsMyClickAction"  Text="Test IP" ID="Button3" runat="server" />
            </div>
</ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
</body>
```

C#

```
protected void upnl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string eventTarget = (this.Request["__EVENTTARGET"] == null) ? string.Empty : this.Request["__EVENTTARGET"];

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventTarget)) return;

    var arg = Request.Params.Get("__EVENTARGUMENT");
    if (arg == null) return;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(arg.ToString()))
    {
        if (arg.ToString().IndexOf("InUse") > -1)
        {
            //Call C# function for in use.
        }

        if (arg.ToString().IndexOf("NotInUse") > -1)
        {
            //Call C# function for not in use.
        }
    }
}

[WebMethod]
public static string TestIP()
{
    //Check for IP status
    if (true)
        return "1";

    //else
    //return "0";
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript, i think this should work

Comment: I already tried CS.RSS as well as CSM.RSS, but couldn't get it to work. If you could add more details to show how, that would be great